# JSF com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In our application with JSF 2.1, when we are trying to inject an application scoped bean, it is throwing the following exception during start up.

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/ecs_home.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean cb
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:73)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:71)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:63)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:417)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1641)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(Tomcat6InjectionProvider.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:219)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.postConstruct(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(Tomcat6InjectionProvider.java:118)
    ... 38 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

An `InvocationTargetException` is thrown when a method that is invoked using reflection throws an exception. In your stacktrace it looks like the postconstruct method of the managed bean threw an exception. The stacktrace of this nested exception should also be available in the server logs.